# Xamarin-PCL iOS SignalR via Https Error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I've got a problem when using SignalR on Xamarin-PCL project. The error occurred when `connection.start()` (The hub url is https) method, But it's worked perfectly on Android.

### This is the error message

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. --->

Comment: did the iamIcarus's answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the SSL/TLS implementation to "Mono (TLS v1.0)"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answered my question "iamicarus". But i've developed on Visual-Studio 2015 and iOS Build properties i don't have "SSL/TLS" menu just have HttpClient Implementation.